# A join or function in Mysql to include all unique items of one column and all unique items of second column

Tags: mysql

[image]

[image]

I need to combine the unique values of one column and the unique values of another column as one new column. As shown in Table example 2

Comment: Replace (or add) sample data screenshot with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union to append all DISTINCT return dates

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(cid int, bid int,cdate varchar(6),rdate varchar(6));
insert into t values
(103,23,'15-mar','26-jan'),
(103,23,'14-apr','26-jan'),
(103,23,'18-may','26-jan');

select cid,bid,cdate,rdate,cdate as newdate from t
union all
(select distinct cid,bid,null,null,rdate from t)
;

+------+------+--------+--------+---------+
| cid  | bid  | cdate  | rdate  | newdate |
+------+------+--------+--------+---------+
|  103 |   23 | 15-mar | 26-jan | 15-mar  |
|  103 |   23 | 14-apr | 26-jan | 14-apr  |
|  103 |   23 | 18-may | 26-jan | 18-may  |
|  103 |   23 | NULL   | NULL   | 26-jan  |
+------+------+--------+--------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

select column1,column2,count(column1) as c1 ,count(column2) as c2 from MyTable having c1 =1 OR c2 =1